# Unresponsive screen on Moto G after Lollipop update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, touchscreen

My Motorola Moto G 1st edition has been updated to Lollipop 5.0.2 and voila! My screen does not respond to any touch whatsoever, even though I can have calls and receive messages but to my utmost misery cannot receive or open them.

Anyone out there with the same problem and any suitable fix?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a bug.

You have to do hard reset after the update:

1. Hold power button for 15 seconds and the device will be forced to shut down
2. Hold power button and volume down button simultaneously to enter fastboot mode and you will have factory reset option
3. Use volume down to navigate and volume up to select desired option
4. Once you have done a factory reset, click power button and the device will reboot.

If you still have touch issues you have to rollback to KitKat by flashing stock firmware.